# calculate optimum point in a list

Tags: data-analysis

Hello guys so I have a list of around 1000 items, and each item has the following properties:

```
price (euros)
points (number)
```

I can have 20 items in a set, and have a budget of `1000` euros.

I want to find the optimum item list so that I have the most points.

I assume there must be a name for this kind of problem, could someone tell me what I need to google to find a solution to this problem? I can do the calculations myself, am just stuck on how the problem is called

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right! Do you happen to know how to solve it with a maximum number of items? As the knapsack does not care how many items go into the sack

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know how to solve it. I merely remembered the name of the problem.